# Is poll() an edge triggered function?

Tags: c++, linux, networking

I am responsible for a server that exports data over a TCP connection.  With each data record that the server transmits, it requires the client to send a short "\n" acknowledgement message back.  I have a customer who claims that the acknowledgement that he sends is not read from the web server.   The following is code that I am using for I/O on the socket:

```
bool can_send = true;
char tx_buff[1024];
char rx_buff[1024];
struct pollfd poll_descriptor;
int rcd;

poll_descriptor.fd = socket_handle;
poll_descriptor.events = POLLIN | POLLOUT;
poll_descriptor.revents = 0;
while(!should_quit && is_connected)
{
   // if we know that data can be written, we need to do this before we poll the OS for
   // events.  This will prevent the 100 msec latency that would otherwise occur
   fill_write_buffer(write_buffer);
   while(can_send && !should_quit && !write_buffer.empty())
   {
      uint4 tx_len = write_buffer.copy(tx_buff, sizeof(tx_buff));
      rcd = ::send(
         socket_handle,
         tx_buff,
         tx_len,
         0);
      if(rcd == -1 && errno != EINTR)
         throw SocketException("socket write failure");
      write_buffer.pop(rcd);
      if(rcd > 0)
         on_low_level_write(tx_buff, rcd);
      if(rcd < tx_len)
         can_send = false;
   }

   // we will use poll for up to 100 msec to determine whether the socket can be read or
   // written
   if(!can_send)
      poll_descriptor.events = POLLIN | POLLOUT;
   else
      poll_descriptor.events = POLLIN;
   poll(&poll_descriptor, 1, 100);

   // check to see if an error has occurred
   if((poll_descriptor.revents & POLLERR) != 0 ||
      (poll_descriptor.revents & POLLHUP) != 0 ||
      (poll_descriptor.revents & POLLNVAL) != 0)
      throw SocketException("socket hung up or socket error");

   // check to see if anything can be written
   if((poll_descriptor.revents & POLLOUT) != 0)
      can_send = true;

   // check to see if anything can be read
   if((poll_descriptor.revents & POLLIN) != 0)
   {
      ssize_t bytes_read;
      ssize_t total_bytes_read = 0;
      int bytes_remaining = 0;
      do
      {
         bytes_read = ::recv(
            socket_handle,
            rx_buff,
            sizeof(rx_buff),
            0);
         if(bytes_read > 0)
         {
            total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
            on_low_level_read(rx_buff,bytes_read);
         }
         else if(bytes_read == -1)
            throw SocketException("read failure");
         ioctl(
            socket_handle,
            FIONREAD,
            &bytes_remaining);
      }
      while(bytes_remaining != 0);

      // recv() will return 0 if the socket has been closed
      if(total_bytes_read > 0)
         read_event::cpost(this);
      else
      {
         is_connected = false;
         closed_event::cpost(this);
      }
   }
}
```

I have written this code based upon the assumption that poll() is a level triggered function and will unblock immediately as long as there is data to be read from the socket.  Everything that I have read seems to back up this assumption.  Is there a reason that I may have missed that would cause the above code to miss a read event?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you've posted. Though I do question your use of the FIONREAD ioctl, you could accomplish the same thing by detecting a read of less than the buffer size. But the way you're using it in combination with `poll` is not a problem.

Comment: 100ms is a pretty aggressive timeout. The Nagle timeout is longer than that, for example. I would use a timeout of at least a couple of seconds over any network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not edge triggered. It is always level triggered. I will have to read your code to answer your actual question though. But that answers the question in the title. :-)

I can see no clear reason in your code why you might be seeing the behavior you are seeing. But the scope of your question is a lot larger than the code you're presenting, and I cannot pretend that this is a complete problem diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

It is level triggered. POLLIN fires if there is data in the socket receive buffer when you poll, and POLLOUT fires if there is room in the socket send buffer (which there almost always is).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your own assessment of the problem (that is, you are blocked on `poll` when you expect to be able to read the acknowledgement), then you will eventually get a timeout.

If the customer's machine is more than 50ms away from your server, then you will always timeout on the connection before receiving the acknowledgement, since you only wait 100ms. This is because it will take a minimum of 50ms for the data to reach the customer, and a minimum of 50ms for the acknowledgement to return.

Comment: Since all of the read/write code is inside of a while loop, I expect the next iteration to take care of the data.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein: I have updated the answer as to why I provided it. If you have more detail about where your problem might actually reside, you should present them in your question.